# In Unity a UI image is resized in web player

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I am making a 2D game with Unity 3D. I have a canvas and an image inside it. When I run the project in Unity I can see the whole image, but when I run it on the web player I can only see a part of it. It looks like the image has been scaled up in the web player.
In the inspector I have set the size of the image to make it fit the size of a canvas. Why is it so big in the web player?

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed that actually the image is not resized. It's simply much less detailed.

Comment: I just found out that in order to maintain the quality of the image it's best to set "Texture Type" to "Advanced".